# Removing Page Breaks with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, nltk

I'm using BeautifulSoup to pull text from an html document which then will get passed to NLTK for some analysis. The HTML file has page breaks in it. The page breaks are causing continuous paragraphs to be split.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
txt = (soup.get_text())
print(txt)
```

The split paragraphs look like this:

The document contains several paragraphs. Each of the paragraphs consists of several

-6-

sentences made of words. The words are made up of letters.

Thoughts on how to remove the page break and have the full paragraph toghether?

Comment: so all your "page breaks" are of the form you describe in the example? i.e.  -page- and then a bunch of blank spaces?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Ya, they are all like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following regular expressions to remove from your text strings that look like: \n\n... -number- \n\n...

```
import re
s=re.sub(r'\n+-[0-9]+-\n+', '', txt)
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: That worked to remove the page number and all of the space but the paragraph is still split in two. 
Now looks like this:                                      
The document contains several paragraphs. Each of the paragraphs consists of several

sentences made of words. The words are made up of letters.

Comment: Hmm. When you say "like this" it looks quite ok to me. I'm not sure what's the problem :)

Comment: There was still a line break between the paragraphs. I used .strip() to remove all space between letters. Not perfect but a workaround for what I was trying to do.

Thanks again for the help! Much appreciated!